# Python - credit card validation section issue

Tags: python, validation, sum, digits

I have been instructed to make a basic credit card validator. However, I'm stuck at the part where all digits of the credit card number must individually add up to be divisible by ten. So for example, 12345 would add up to 15 but then return False while 1234 would return True.

The code I have currently:

```
for c in cardnum:
  if sum(c) % 10 != 0:
    return False
  return True
```

The error I'm having right now is the result saying that there's a TypeError for unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: What is  `cardnum` ? and its format?

Comment: More than likely `cardnum` is a list or tuple of strings, not ints.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that `c` seems to be a string and so you can't add up its characters in the way you want. Perhaps you should convert them to integers first:

```
if sum([int(d) for d in c]) % 10 != 0:
```

This is a list comprehension: if `c='1234'`, the code between square brackets generates the list of integers: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` which you can pass to the `sum()` function without any problems.